# how to manage view controllers in a sequential pattern - swift

Tags: ios, paging, uicontainerview

I'm trying to implement sth like images below. there are some views that should be displayed in a sequential order and a bar above them shows the flow of tasks.

[image]

as it is shown, first profile view should be displayed. when the user clicks on `Go to Next View Button` second view (price view) should be displayed. the top bar shows the current view where we are in it. I've tried [PagingMenuController](https://github.com/kitasuke/PagingMenuController) already to create a menu with views and then disable scrolling. but `PagingMenuController` loads all views at the same time and also i don't know how to go to next menu item within child views. now I'm thinking of a container view might be helpful but i didn't use container view so far and i don't know it's good for my purpose or not.
also i want that top bar without swiping between views (only on buttons) and one enable view at the same time.
any helps would be apprectiated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is both broad and vague. My answer is also going to be fairly high level. I suggest you follow my outline, and if you get stuck on a particular step, post your code, tell us about the problem you're having, and we can help you fix it.

This is pretty simple. Create custom view controller. Give it a container view at the bottom that would contain the current child view controller. Use view controller transition methods to switch between child view controllers. You'll want to add layout anchors to each new child view controllers to pin all of it's view's edges to the edges of the container view.

Create a custom control on top to show the dot and highlight the title of the current view controller.

If you want the next/previous buttons to be on the child view controllers, put them there, and add a delegate property to all the child view controllers that points to the parent view controller, with next and previous methods.

BTW, in languages, like English, where text is laid out from left to right, I would think your first page would be on the left and the last page would be on the right. (I think it makes more sense for profile to be on the left and pay on the right.)

Comment: Thats a good help. i wanted to see if container is good or not. I'll use it and ask in need. thanks